# Ignoring a table's cell class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the data off [this](http://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/league-tables/rankings?s=Accounting+%26+Finance) website to create a table. I plan on creating a function to iterate through every subject but testing on just Accounting & Finance first. So far I have the following code:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

main_url = 'http://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/league-tables/rankings?s=Accounting+%26+Finance'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(main_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    title = soup.find('h2').contents[0]
    title = " ".join(title.split())
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'leagueTable hoverHighlight narrow'})
    headers = []
    rows = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        for item in row.findAll('th'):
            for link in item.findAll('a', text=True):
                headers.append(link.contents[0])

        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        rows.append(cols)

        for idx, i in enumerate(headers):
            if 'Click' in i:
                del headers[idx]
        for idx, i in enumerate(headers):
            if '2016' in i:
                del headers[idx]

    print headers
    print rows
```

Which returns

```
[u'CUG Rank ', u'University Name ', u'Entry Standards', u'Student Satisfaction', u'Research Quality', u'Graduate Prospects', u'Overall Score']
[u'1', u'2', u'Strathclyde', u'517', u'', u'4.14', u'', u'3.17', u'', u'81', u'', u'100.0']
```

I'm going to insert an additional header in the second index to account for the 2015 column so that's not an issue but the issue lies  where

```
td class="quintile detailColumn"
```

as these returns a null after each value (these are the bar charts under each measure). How do I scrape every other td while excluding the td class="quintile detailColumn"?

I would specify all the classes to use in the findAll and do a 'quintile' not in but the second column (2015) doesn't have a td class. Any help would be appreciated, I'm happy to clarify anything I've missed. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately ``BeautifulSoup`` is not that versatile. You have to iterate over the ``td``s yourself and skip ``quintile``. I would perhaps try to collect both lists and then subtract ``quintile detailColumn`` from ``detailColumn`` but not quite sure if it works in practise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ".get"  to obtain the class with default value if it's missing. Then just check if that value doesn't equal to what you want to exclude.

Like this (note that the .get('class') returns list of words in class rather than string):

```
cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols if ele.get('class',"my default value") != ['quintile', 'detailColumn']]
```

Comment: This works, thank you :) I'm confused as to what the "my default value" does though? Is it literally just a random string/placeholder?

Comment: `ele.get('class',"my default value")` returns the class of the ele variable (td tag) if it has a class. 

If it doesn't have a 'class' then it returns string "my default value". You can replace "my default value" with anything you like (for example None) and that code will work the same, as long as you don't put `['quintile', 'detailColumn']` there.